# Specific merging in Telerik RadGridView

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik, telerik-grid, radgridview

How i'm able to make specific merging (or grouping) as on screenshot

[image]

I made column header grouping

[image]

But i cann't add cell above 69 and 10, which will show their sum

Comment: are you looking for `ColumnSpan`?

Comment: @Bizhan I'm looking for a way to split cell on 4 cells and then span top cells

Comment: Then use both `ColumnSpan` and `RowSpan`. BTW, there is no such thing as "splitting a cell". You can only "merge cells" (i.e. span)